# Issue executing Perl CGI from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl, cgi

How do I get my Perl script to execute from JavaScript called from an HTML form's 'action' attribute?

I am using scripts built by other people mostly, and the basic gist of it is that I need to call the CGI script from the JS function.

I have to do it this way because it was the best I could come up with based on whether or not the device is mobile.

I need to pass some checkboxes to the Perl script and return some files based on the checkbox states. I know the Perl script works perfectly without having to execute the JavaScript, but I don't know how to check if a device is mobile or not in Perl, and I do in JS.

All I need is to execute the CGI script, passing it the same information as if it was being called directly from the form, but it does nothing.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function downloadFiles(){
    var isMobile = function(){
        try {document.createEvent("TouchEvent"); return true;}
        catch(e) {return false;}
    }
    && (/Mobi/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
    if(!isMobile){
        $.ajax({
            type:"Post",
            url:"https://www.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/myPerlScript.cgi",
            success:function(msg){$("#myHtmlForm").html(msg.d);}
        });
    }
}
```

I don't rightly know what 'msg' or its property 'd' is, and I don't even know if my form should be the element where it is.  So what I am missing here?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: You could try to download the file with jQuery file download plugin: http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: @Meloviz url: should be `/cgi-bin/myPerlScript.cgi`

Comment: @bob what would that do?

Comment: When you run this and look at your developer tools in the browser, do you see anything going wrong? Is there a 404 or a 500 error response? Is there a response at all? Or maybe some syntax error? If you can see that there's a 200 response, look at the content. It seems your CGI responds with an `application/json` content type (or similar) and there is an object like `{ 'd' : ... }` in the body of the response. Can you verify this?

Comment: *I have to do it this way because it was the best I could come up with based on whether or not the device is mobile or not* - I'd recommend that you use [media queries](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to work out whether a visitor is using a mobile device

Comment: @ikegami the issue that I am having is that, as I said in my post, it does nothing. The page doesn't reload, the click event doesn't seem to fire, literally nothing happens when I click on the form's submit button. I've narrowed down the issue to this bit of JS as the culprit.

Comment: @DaveCross I went through a lot of research on figuring out the best way to tell if a device is mobile, and I probably will add a media query to my if block, but I'm not as concerned about that right because even without the if block, my script won't run properly.

Comment: @simbaque Nothing appears to be wrong other than it does nothing. No error comes up, nothing at all. There is no response. I thought it might be a syntax error, but I've been through the code a dozen times. I even separated it out line by line, block by block, and there seems to be nothing wrong with the syntax. It is as exactly as I've posted here. And I mean literally, this is all that is in the else part of the if block, and there are no other local variables.

Comment: @mkHun I've tried with both absolute and relative URLs, and neither works, so even if that is a problem I'm having, it's not the only one. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Meloviz, Re "*it does nothing*", That's completely wrong, so again I ask: What problem are you having? Is the call to `ajax` not being reached? Is the call to `ajax` calling the `error` callback instead of the `success` one? Is the browser not making the https request? Is the https request failing? Is the request succeeding but your script isn't getting executed? Is the script getting executed but returning a different result than expected? Which of these do you incorrectly call "nothing"?

Comment: @ikegami I realize that "It does nothing" is not technical, but that is the result. I tested the JS function, and the part that doesn't act the way it is supposed to is the call to the CGI script. Everything else about the JS function works perfect, and the CGI script works perfectly if it is called from the HTML form rather than the JS function. I get no error, I get no callback that I can tell, I don't know if the request is even calling the CGI script because I get nothing in return to tell what is going on. I'm pretty much a complete noob when it comes to this stuff, so any help is great.

Comment: I really don't care that it works if you do something different you can't do here. You need to specify what *does* happen (instead of trying to justify that it's ok to say nothign happened) So again I ask: What problem are you having? Is the call to `ajax` not being reached? Is the call to `ajax` calling the `error` callback instead of the `success` one? Is the browser not making the https request? Is the https request failing? Is the request succeeding but your script isn't getting executed? Is the script getting executed but returning a different result than expected?

Comment: @ikegami I can only assume that my problem is that the ajax call is not built properly. What else does it need in order to run the CGI script? The function executes up to and past the ajax, but nothing returns from the ajax call. The complete code for the ajax call is up in my post; there is nothing else to it but that. To answer the rest, I assume the default error callback is called because it's not explicitly set, I don't believe the browser is making the https request because the script should return something but does not return anything. Does that help?

Comment: I did to the best of my ability. Can you suggest something for me to do to answer those questions more adequately for you?

Comment: Re "*nothing returns from the ajax call*", That's normal. The first "a" in AJAX stands for "asynchronous". When the response arrives, the `success` callback is called. If an error occurs, the `error` callback is called instead.

Comment: Gladly. Which question do you have a problem answering?

Comment: Ah, thank you. Your comment helped me be able to answer one of your questions. The error callback is what gets called.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I wasn't building the ajax statement completely or correctly. I didn't add any data that I needed to pass into the CGI script.

Here's the ajax statement I ended up with:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/cgi-bin/myPerlScript.cgi",
    data:$("#myHtmlForm").serialize(),
    error:function badCall(){location.href="https://www.mywebsite.com/error.html";}
});
```

Thank you @ikegami, @mkHun, @simbabque, and @DaveCross!